# Unexpected Behaviour shown while opening the pop up screen in iPad usingjquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am opening a pop up screen on clinking the header button actually after open of pop up I fill my field than my keyboard will open. Along with black screen also open. How to remove this unnatural behaviour. Actually the the theme move upward when open the keyboard.
I used simple code :

http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/jDKDW/

```html
<div data-role="page" id="Home" > 
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" >
            <h1 class="ui-title"  id="hdr" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 100px;">My Cases</h1>
            <div class="ui-btn-right" id="headerButtons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <a href="#UserSettingScreen" data-transition="none" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b" id="Setting" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">Setting</a>
                <a href="#CaseInformationScreen" data-transition="none" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b" data-rel="popup" id="Add" data-position-to="window">Add</a>
                <a href="" data-role="button" data-transition="none" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-rel="popup"id="Edit" data-position-to="window">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="folderData" >
            </ul>
            <!-- **************Case Information Pop up Start*******************-->
            <div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen" data-close-btn="none"  data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >

                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="Cancel">Cancel</a>
                    <h1>Case Information</h1>
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="AddButton">Add</a>
                </div>

                <div data-role="content">
                    <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Case Name:</label>
                        <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="caseName_h" >
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;" >Case Date:</label>
                        <!--input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="date" class="caseDate_h"  -->
                        <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}'/>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="textarea-12">Textarea:</label>
                        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="text-12" class="caseTextArea_h"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Case Information Pop up End************************-->

            <!--   User setting Pop up Start-->


    </div>
    </div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you explain again what is the problem, it only exists on ipad ?

Comment: Yes actually i am testing the code in Ipad and Android tablet..

Comment: I will explain the problem again .I have one pop up screen on button click(+ button) on header .I click that button Pop up is open .But when i click the text field the key board is open and pop up goes up but the black theam also goes up (as shown in first pic) so it look awkward ..