# How to set default current date using jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to set default date on text field.Actually I have one button on click pop up screen display in there  is date field i what to show current date on date.

```
  <div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen" data-close-btn="none"  data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >

                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="Cancel">Cancel</a>
                    <h1>Case Information</h1>
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="AddButton">Add</a>
                </div>

                <div data-role="content">
                    <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Case Name:</label>
                        <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="caseName_h" autocorrect="off">
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="caseDate" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;" >Case Date:</label>
                        <input name="caseDate" id="caseDate" value="" type="date" class="caseDate_h" >
                           <!--input name="mydate2" id="mydate2" type="date" data-role="datebox" class="caseDate_h" data-options='{"mode": "calbox","useNewStyle":true,"zindex":1200}'/-->
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="textarea-12">Case Notes :</label>
                        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="text-12" class="caseTextArea_h" autocorrect="off"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I need to set date when this pop up open on this field..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Ndc2b/

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <a href="#CaseInformationScreen" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop">Basic Popup</a>
                <div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen" data-close-btn="none"  data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
                    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >

                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="Cancel">Cancel</a>
                        <h1>Case Information</h1>
                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="AddButton">Add</a>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="content">
                        <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Case Name:</label>
                            <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="caseName_h" autocorrect="off"/>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="caseDate" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;" >Case Date:</label>
                            <input name="caseDate" id="caseDate" value="" type="date" class="caseDate_h" />

                        </div>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="textarea-12">Case Notes :</label>
                            <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-12" id="text-12" class="caseTextArea_h" autocorrect="off"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).on( "popupafteropen", "#CaseInformationScreen",function( event, ui ) {
        var today = new Date();   
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();    

        $('#caseDate').val(dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy);    
    });        
});
```

Comment: please also see this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741096/how-to-resize-the-text-area-in-query-mobile/17741481?noredirect=1#comment25866078_17741481

Comment: Lets fix it. Tell me what is not working? But first five me a sec, I will incorporate this answer with your own example.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7JqRG/5/ 'onLoad' must be changed to 'No wrap - in <body>'. This is option that can be found in top left corner of jsfiddle. For somer reason page event will not work if onLoad option is selected.

Comment: Have you looked at my new example, it is made directly from your fiddle?

Comment: yes  ..Please click(+) button and pop up show but date is not set on date field..

Comment: Oh this is a Chrome problem, I was testing this in FF. Let me take a look.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7JqRG/6/ This example works on web kit browsers, unfortunately I can test it on iPad right now. Also FF = Firefox. I can confirm this works on Android so it should work also on iOS.

Comment: ok..it is working ..is this possible to add done button on date picker coming in ipad..

Comment: or it is possible after selecting it should be hide (date picker)

Comment: From what I know it is not possible, mainly because it is done one an iOS level.

Comment: can you check this problem also..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707575/unexpected-behaviour-shown-while-opening-the-pop-up-screen-in-ipad-usingjquery-m

Comment: Hi 

can you please tell me how to  block selecting future date in type="date".in query mobile?

Comment: I will need to check it, but I think it will be enough to change type="date" to type="text", let me try it.

Comment: Tell me this, if you dont want to change date any more, isn't it better for this field to be type="text" from the beginning?

Comment: Ahaaaaaaa ok I understand it now.

Comment: @Gajotres example that works for me is http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7JqRG/6/, thanks. datepicker drove me crazy until this sample

Answer (score -1):

There's a very simple solution.
This is what I did:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date1").datepicker();
    $("#date1").datepicker('setDate', 'today');
});

<input type="text" id="date1">
```